# How can I retrieve files with User-Agent headers in Python 3?

Tags: python, request, user-agent, urllib

I'm trying to write a (simple) piece of code to download files off the internet. The problem is, some of these files are on websites that block the default python User-Agent headers. For example:

```
import urllib.request as html
html.urlretrieve('http://stackoverflow.com', 'index.html')
```

returns

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`
```

Normally, I would set the headers in the request, such as:

```
import urllib.request as html
request = html.Request('http://stackoverflow.com', headers={"User-Agent":"Firefox"})
response = html.urlopen(request)
```

however, as `urlretrieve` doesn't work with requests for some reason, this isn't an option.

Are there any simple-ish solutions to this (that don't include importing a library such as requests)? I've noticed that urlretrieve is part of the legacy interface posted over from Python 2, is there anything I should be using instead?

I tried creating a custom FancyURLopener class to handle retrieving files, but that caused more problems than it solved, such as creating empty files for links that 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subclass `URLopener` and set the `version` class variable to a different user-agent then continue using urlretrieve.

Or you can simply use your second method and save the response to a file only after checking that `code == 200`.