# Access denied while scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to create a script to go on to https://www.size.co.uk/featured/footwear/ and scrape the content but somehow when i run the script, i got access denied. Here is the code:

```
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
url = urlopen('https://www.size.co.uk/')
print BS(url, 'lxml')
```

The output is

```
<html><head>
<title>Access Denied</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Access Denied</h1>

You don't have permission to access "http://www.size.co.uk/" on this server.
<p>
Reference #18.6202655f.1498945327.11002828
</p></body>
</html>
```

When i try it with other websites, the code works fine and also when i use Selenium, nothing happens but i still want to know how to bypass this error without using Selenium. But when i use Selenium on different website like http://www.footpatrol.co.uk/shop i got the same Access Denied error, here is the code for footpatrol:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('C:\Users\V\Desktop\PY\web_scrape\phantomjs.exe')
driver.get('http://www.footpatrol.com')
pageSource = driver.page_source
soup = BS(pageSource, 'lxml')
print soup
```

Output is:

```
<html><head>
<title>Access Denied</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Access Denied</h1>

You don't have permission to access "http://www.footpatrol.co.uk/" on this 
server.<p>
Reference #18.6202655f.1498945644.110590db


</p></body></html>
```

Comment: Set the user agent header to look like a browser.

Comment: @Alen You mean using Selenium ?

Comment: What python are you on?

Comment: @Coldspeed I'm on python 2.7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I retrieve files with User-Agent headers in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32115815/how-can-i-retrieve-files-with-user-agent-headers-in-python-3)

Comment: @DYZ OP is on Python2 though.

Comment: @DYZ It's possible but the problem is even if i use selenium, the site still doesnt give me access.

Comment: Why don't you try `requests` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

url = 'https://www.size.co.uk/'
agent = {"User-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get(url, headers=agent)
print (BS(page.content, 'lxml'))
```

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
  headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 
  Firefox/50.0'}
  source=requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
  print(source)
```