# Python Request Always Failing to One Page?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm completely new to this, it works on every website but this one? any idea why?
No error, just never completes.

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page = requests.get("https://www.argos.co.uk/product/8892203/")
    
print(page)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This website is agent aware.

You can check it with simple `curl`.

```
curl -s https://www.argos.co.uk/product/8892203/ | head -3
```

returns

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
```

With agent set

```
curl -s -A "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0" https://www.argos.co.uk/product/8892203/
```

you get proper website

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charSet="utf-8"/> ....
```

Comment: If i do this code it still fails?

import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

agent = {"User-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'}


page = requests.get("https://www.argos.co.uk/product/8466660", headers=agent)
    
print(page)

Answer (score 0):

The page you are trying to access is blocked,
This is the answer that you get when trying to access the page:

```
> <html><head>\n<title>Access Denied</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Access
> Denied</h1>\n \nYou don\'t have permission to access
> "http://www.argos.co.uk/product/8892203/" on this
> server.<p>\nReference
> #18.8d0c1502.1615389605.5585b8b\n\n\n</p></body></html>
```

You can try to use an agent to mask your request like in this answer:

[Access denied while scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44865673/access-denied-while-scraping)

Comment: Ok thanks, how do you know? like how can I see the error etc? this is my first day in python